# Secure a password used for encryption within .NET assembly

Tags: c#, security

I have inherited a project written in C# / .NET 4 which rolls its own symmetric encryption assembly. Assembly is written to use RijndaelManaged but includes the seed in clear text within the assembly. A simple decompile of the assembly reveals the seed and renders all the encryption moot.

So for now I don't want to have to change everything security wise and in the mean time keep using the encryption Assembly/DLL. So is the best way to temporarily improve security to store the password in the registry and have the DLL access it from there? At least that way the machine itself would need to also be penetrated to get the password before someone could use that to brute force logins?

Comment: Well, yes. That would be somewhat more secure. Although how you get it into the registry is something of a question. If the installer puts it there, and it's the same for every user, then you've just made the problem slightly more difficult for an attacker.

Comment: It depends on what data you are trying to protect. What is the data that is being protected, and where is it encrypted and where is it decrypted?

Comment: As Jim points out, you need the password to be set independently of any code you provide. I.e. a user enters it. Given that, I'd say that the Data Protection API should be used to actually encrypt and decrypt the data as needed. After the user provides the password, encrypt it using DPAPI and _then_ save it somewhere (e.g. the registry). When your program needs the value, use DPAPI again to decrypt. Then only someone with that user's login credentials can access it. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As @PeterDuniho mentioned, using DPAPI is a good start

Comment: @Jim At this point there is no installer as application is ASP.NET MVC. so could put it into the registry by hand. This encryption is used to encrypt the user password which is used for user access to the entire application. There is no salt just this one magic string used as the seed.

Comment: @Peter Looking at ProtectedData that looks like the go, but is it portable to another machine? It uses either user or machine credentials. As this is an ASP.NET application using the user credentials won't work if this is moved to another machine or a different user is used for the ASP.NET, and then using the machine credentials is also no good. Have I missed something really obvious here?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the question. It's true that the DPAPI encryption is user-specific (machine-specific if the account's a local account, AFAIK, and of course if you're using the machine credentials). But why is this an impediment? You would simply require the user/administrator to provide the data again in that scenario, so that it can be re-stored using the new credentials. The key here is to not embed the data in your program itself.

Comment: @PeterDuniho OK, I get you... So when the application is "installed" to a new web server go through the process of providing the original seed so that the existing entries in the database can still be decrypted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use asymmetric encryption to secure the seed.

Install the private key on the machine and only give read permissions to the account running your ASP.NET app pool. Encrypt the seed with the public key and store it in the registry or on disk somewhere. Now the web application can use the private key to decrypt the seed.

See the section on Asymmetric encryption here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as0w18af(v=vs.110).aspx